# Application timeout feature

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I am developing an AIR 2.0 application, and would like to put an inactivity timeout feature into it.  (i.e: if the user doesn't press a key for 5 minutes then the application logs the user out. I have implemented the native timeout features available in the flash.utils library, and listen for mouse or keyboard events to clear / reset the timeout in my main MXML.   The only problem is that my application uses TitleWindows and the keyboard events don't appear to bubble up (or back) into the main Mxml where I'm listening for them.  Therefore my app thinks that there is inactivity even when keys and mouse events are firing in the Title windows.

Is there a way that I can inherently listen for keyboard and mouse events globally?  the prospect of adding listeners to every TitleWindow (and checking to see if it is open or not) seems quite daunting.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you can add your Keyboard event listeners to the entire stage, instead of specific movie clips.

Answer (score 0):

From anywhere in a UIComponent (probably the main UI class):

```
private function onCreationComplete():void
{
   stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.DOWN, onKeyboard);
}

private function onKeyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a combination of the focus issue and listeining for events in 'stage'.  Working fine now - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into a focus issue which is always frustrating, check my answer here-

[Event listener to keyboard event not listening in a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626608/event-listener-to-keyboard-event-not-listening-in-a-module/6627469#6627469)

Try the textinput suggestion at bottom of answer to test if this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks Nate, looks like the focus issue was part of the problem.

Comment: No prob, it's irritating that adobe themselves don't point out the focus issue.  You can see in their own page of examples they're using .setFocus() in all the example code -yet never mention it in the page description / instructions otherwise.  Bizarre :)